# Passing ArrayList from RecyclerView into another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to pass the data, which is set in the mainactivity.java into another activity(infoPage.java) but i cant seem to get it working.

MainActivity.java

```
data = new ArrayList<>();
       data.add( new CarData("Toyota Camry 2010 2.4V","Automatic","5 Seater","Petrol/Full","RM 40 /h",R.drawable.camry2010));


       recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.browsedRecycler);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
       adapter = new Adapter(this,data);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

constructor for model class

```
public CarData(String title , String trans, String seats, String fuel, String price, int imgID) {

        this.title = title;
        this.trans = trans;
        this.seats = seats;
        this.fuel = fuel;
        this.price = price;
        this.imgID = imgID;
    }
```

Adapter class

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {


    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<CarData> data;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<CarData>data) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlist,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //to bind the textview with data received

       String title = data.get(position).getTitle();
       String trans = data.get(position).getTrans();
       String seat = data.get(position).getSeats();
       String fuel = data.get(position).getFuel();
       String price = data.get(position).getPrice();
       int imgid = data.get(position).getImgID();
        holder.texttitle.setText(title);
        holder.trans.setText(trans);
        holder.seats.setText(seat);
        holder.fuel.setText(fuel);
        holder.price.setText(price);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(imgid);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView texttitle,trans,seats,fuel,price;
        ImageView imageView;
       public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {

                   Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),infoPage.class);
                   i.putExtra("title", (data.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition())));
                   view.getContext().startActivity(i);
               }
           });

           texttitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
           trans = itemView.findViewById(R.id.carTrans);
           seats = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seats);
           fuel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fuel);
           price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
           imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
       }
   }
```

my infopage.java has nothing much yet basically, just the declaration of the textviews and imageviews
infoPage.java

```
 TextView textView;
    ImageView carimage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cars_info_page);

        textView=findViewById(R.id.detailText);
        carimage=findViewById(R.id.carsimg);
```

I've figured it out myself thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

for passing an ArrayList to another activity you should make your model class Parcelable, for doing this you can use the Parcelable plugin that adds some required codes to your model class and make it Parcelable. you can use different plugins for this work, but the plugin that I use for my projects is "Android ParceLable Code Generator" by Michal Charmas.
You can download this plugin from the below path:
File-> Settings-> Plugins
After this , you should use putParcelableArrayListExtra() method to pass arraylist to destenation activity.
You can get the Arraylist in destination Activity using getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra() method that needs one parameter and that parameter is the String key that you specify in the first Activity

Comment: alright thanks for the answer! but what do i do after that? how do i insert the passed data into separate textviews and imageviews?

Comment: By this work, You are passing the hole of the list to info Activity, if the info activity must show just info of clicked item, you do not need to pass hole of the list, just the pass the item that you need and instead of using putParcelableArrayListExtra method, use putExtra method. this method has an overload that has two parameters, the first is String key and the second is a Parcelable object.

Comment: and when you have the object of your model in your info activity you can easily use getter methods for getting values and set them in ImageViews and TextViews

Comment: Im sorry i still have a lot to learn but when you mention i need to pass a string key and a parcelable object do you mean like this ? intent.putExtra("key",data.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()));
Many Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: yes ,this code will work but before that make sure that your model class is Parcelable

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you are sending the data in wrong way. The right way is to  use getters and setters.
If you don't know about them then you can have a look at this -
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/recyclerview-in-andriod-with-java/

So, you need to do changes in the class where you have created constructors(Let's say Data Class) and use getters and setters there.

Initialize Data class in Mainactivity and set your data with the help of setters and then initialize the Data class in Adapter and get your data with the help of getters.

Comment: I shouldve mentioned or posted my getter setters in the codes, my apologies. Right now, i can pass data into my recyclerview but i cant get Those data and pass it into another activity when i click onto a specific item on my recyclerview. Lets just say i have "Coca Cola, 1234, $5" for the first item on my recyclerview, when i click on it how do i set Coca cola 1234 and $5 for my other textviews in my other activity? Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Okay! so I get your point. the problem is in the data you are passing i.e. data.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()). i have know idea what is this, maybe you are trying to send data in bulk. I would suggest to send data seperately. Like considering your Cola example, send data like this-

Comment: intent.putExtra("name", name.getText());     intent.putExtra("price", price.getText());    intent.putExtra("amount", amount.getText());